# How to change where Gradle 'Test' task saves file

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, build.gradle, appium, allure

I'm running into the following error when attempting to run my Appium testing framework. It seems like the "Test" task is trying to save the Allure report to a directory within the `build` directory and seems it can't write to it. How can I edit where this task saves the report? If anyone can point me in the right direction on where to look I'd be super grateful. Thank you so much!

```
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':test' (type 'Test').
  - Type 'org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test' property '$1' is not writable because '/Users/my_name/Documents/application_name/build/allure-results' is not a file.
```

This is my test code:

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test
import robot.WelcomeScreen

class LoginTest: BaseTest() {

    private val robot = WelcomeScreen()

    @Test(description = "User can log in with valid email and password")
    fun logInUsingValidEmailAndPassword() {
        // Obtain login screen from Robot
        robot.clickLoginOnWelcomeScreen()
            // perform actions and assertions from Robot
    }
}
```

And the below is my `build.gradle` file. I was trying to follow the same steps as the author of this repository https://github.com/automateITpro/appium-with-kotlin.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "io.qameta.allure:allure-gradle:2.3"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.6.21'
    id 'java'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'io.qameta.allure'

allure {
    version = '2.4.1'
    autoconfigure = true
    aspectjweaver = true
    allureJavaVersion = "18.0.1"
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.2'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.2'

    implementation "io.insert-koin:koin-core:3.2.0"
    testImplementation "io.insert-koin:koin-test:3.2.0"

    implementation 'io.appium:java-client:8.1.1'
    implementation 'org.testng:testng:7.6.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.4.21"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.4.21"
    implementation "com.github.automatedowl:allure-environment-writer:1.0.0"
}

configurations {
    testCompile
}

test {
    maxHeapSize = "6144m"
    jvmArgs "-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=6144m"

    useTestNG() {
        useDefaultListeners = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The allure report can be customised to save results and report to specific paths, see amendment of your build.gradle below:

```
allure {
    version = '2.4.1'
    autoconfigure = true
    aspectjweaver = true
    allureJavaVersion = "18.0.1"
    resultsDir = file('/path/to/test/results')
    reportDir = file('/path/to/trst/report')
}
```

Further details for configuration of Allure Reports can be found here: [Allure Framework | Reporting | Gradle | Full Configuration](https://docs.qameta.io/allure/#_full_configuration)